# React Native dynamic multiple dropdown(picker)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, dropdown

I want to implement multiple pickers, the number of pickers will be based upon the value which we select in a textbox.
The problem in dynamic picker (through loop) is that I can't use "selectedValue" property of Picker properly.Can't set value of Picker Dynamically.

eg. code,

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Picker } from 'react-native';

let no_of_pickers = [1,2,3];//3 pickers can be increase or decreased
export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            selectValue = [0,0,0]
        };
    }

    setValue(value,index){
        let selectValue = this.state.selectValue;
        selectValue[index] = value;
        this.setState({
          selectValue:selectValue
        });//this won't set selected value on picker
    }
    render(){
        let pickers = no_of_pickers.map((value, i) => {
            return (
                <View key={i}>
                  <Picker
                    selectedValue={this.state.selectValue[i]}
                    onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => {this.setValue(itemValue, i)}}>
                      <Picker.Item value='0' label={'Select Value'} />
                      <Picker.Item value='1' label={'Value 1'} />
                      <Picker.Item value='2' label={'Value 2'} />
                      <Picker.Item value='3' label={'Value 3'} />
                  </Picker>
                </View>
            );
        });
        return (
            {pickers}
        );
    }
}
```

In above code the function setValue should set the picker value in UI, but only state value changed but value not selected in UI.

Comment: You need to provide a little more context and your code to get help.

Comment: Can Describe more Detail or UI Deign or Library you are using. https://github.com/beefe/react-native-actionsheet

Comment: Given example code to better understand what I want to implement.

Comment: @Shivam , I am facing same problem , Are you able to solve this issue ?

Comment: @sid No,I followed a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use react-native-smart-picker because vanilla RN doesn't like when you .map data.

```
 render() {
    return (
        <ScrollView >
            <View style={{ flex: 1, marginTop: 20 }}>
                {this.state.models.length > 0 ?
                    <ScrollView >
                        <SmartPicker

                            expanded={this.state.expanded}
                            selectedValue={this.state.selectedModel}
                            label='Select Model'
                            onValueChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
                        >
                            {
                                this.state.models.map((ele) => {
                                    return (<Picker.Item label={ele} value={ele} />)
                                })
                            }
                            <Picker.Item label='Select Model' value='4Runner' />
                        </SmartPicker>
                        <Button block onPress={() => this.props.vehicleModel(this.state.selectedModel)}>
                            <Text>Done</Text>
                        </Button>
                    </ScrollView>
                    : <Spinner />}

            </View>

        </ScrollView>
    );
}
```